On compact embeddings of Sobolev space.
I am finding compact embeddings about the Bessel potential space or Sobolev space.
In the reference
P.L. De Nápoli, and I. Drelichman, “Elementary Proofs of Embedding Theorems for Potential Spaces of Radial Functions,” in Methods of Fourier Analysis and Approximation Theory, edited by M. Ruzhansky and S. Tikhonov, (Springer International Publishing, Cham, 2016), pp. 115–138
an article by Lions is mentioned
P.-L. Lions, “Symétrie et compacité dans les espaces de Sobolev,” Journal of Functional Analysis 49(3), 315–334 (1982).
where the importan theorem is:
Theorem (Lions) Let $N>1,\, s>0,\, 1\leq p<\infty$. Let $p*=\frac{Np}{N-sp}$ if $sp<N$ and $p*=\infty$ if $sp\geq N$. The restriction to $W_{\text{radial}}^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$
of the embedding $W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)\hookrightarrow L^q(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is compact if $p<q<p*$
Question. If $sp\geq N>1$, Is the embedding $W_{\text{radial}}^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)\hookrightarrow L_{\text{radial}}^q(\mathbb{R}^N)$ compact for any $1\leq p<q<\infty$?
I ask this to know if I understood correctly. Thanks.
